# How to add black border to points in PCA score plot using fviz_pca_ind?

Tags: r, visualization, pca, factoextra

I am currently working on visualizing a PCA score plot in R using the fviz_pca_ind function from the factoextra package. However, I am facing an issue in applying a black border to the points in the plot.

Despite specifying `col.ind = "black"` in the function, I am unable to get a black border around the points.

Here is a minimal reproducible example with the relevant portion of my R code:

```
# Load required libraries
library(factoextra)
library(ggplot2)

# Create sample data
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(
  Place = rep(c("A", "B", "C"), each = 10),
  Score1 = rnorm(30),
  Score2 = rnorm(30)
)

My_PCA <- prcomp(df[, c("Score1", "Score2")])

# Plot scores
fviz_pca_ind(My_PCA,
             geom = "point",
             pointsize = rep(5, nrow(df)),
             habillage = df$Place,
             col.ind = "black",
             fill = df$Place,
             palette = c("red", "green", "blue"),
             repel = TRUE
) +
  scale_shape_manual(values = c(21, 24, 22)) +
  labs(title=NULL) +
  theme(legend.position="none")
```

I have reviewed the documentation and tried various approaches, but none seem to work. I have also considered using different parameters such as alpha, but they did not resolve the problem. Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know, if this finds your answer, but i trie from my side, I tried to put point aswell as boarder
some link i got here https://www.biostars.org/p/417894/

```
# Load required libraries
library(factoextra)
library(ggplot2)

# Create sample data
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(
  Place = rep(c("A", "B", "C"), each = 10),
  Score1 = rnorm(30),
  Score2 = rnorm(30)
)

My_PCA <- prcomp(df[, c("Score1", "Score2")])

# Plot scores with black border using ggplot2
my_plot <- fviz_pca_ind(My_PCA,
                        geom = "point",
                        pointsize = rep(5, nrow(df)),
                        habillage = df$Place,
                        fill = df$Place,
                        palette = c("red", "green", "blue"),
                        repel = TRUE,
                        ggtheme = theme_bw()  # Add this line
) +
  scale_shape_manual(values = c(21, 24, 22)) +
  labs(title=NULL) +
  theme(legend.position="none")

# Add a black border around the points using ggplot2 layer
my_plot + geom_point(color = "black", size = 2, alpha = 0.7)+scale_color_manual(values = c("black", "black", "black"))
```

[image]

Comment: Adding `scale_color_manual(values = c("black", "black", "black"))` did exactly what I wanted. Thanks!

Comment: @Gianluca , Hi and what about down answer, I mean second answer, any suggestion from your side, like any mistakes, any fault, your reply will help me to understand me something which I may not know

Comment: I always go for simpler code, and the first answer was spot on. The code below is a bit more complicated and doesn't quite do what I want. Instead of getting black borders, the points end up with coloured ones. Also, the colours are mixed up - red points get blue borders and blue points get red borders. I'm sure it can be fixed, but since the first way worked so well, I'm not gonna dig further into the second one.

Answer (score 0):

or this below one , found here https://github.com/kevinblighe/PCAtools/issues/35

```
# Load required libraries
library(factoextra)
library(ggplot2)

# Create sample data
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(
  Place = rep(c("A", "B", "C"), each = 10),
  Score1 = rnorm(30),
  Score2 = rnorm(30)
)

# Create a new 'Group' variable based on 'Place'
df$Group <- ifelse(df$Place == "A", "red",
                   ifelse(df$Place == "B", "green", "blue"))

My_PCA <- prcomp(df[, c("Score1", "Score2")])

# Plot scores with black border using fviz_pca_ind
fviz_pca_ind(My_PCA,
             geom = "point",
             pointsize = rep(3.5, nrow(df)),
             habillage = df$Place,
             fill = df$Group,
             palette = c("red", "green", "blue"),
             repel = TRUE,
             stroke = 1  # Set the border width
) +
  scale_shape_manual(values = c(21, 24, 22)) +
  labs(title=NULL) +
  theme(text = element_text(size = 20),
        axis.text.x = element_text(size = 20),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size = 20),
        legend.key = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_blank(),
        panel.border = element_rect(linetype = "solid", fill = NA)
  )
```

[image]